# Linux file transfer between server automatically when a file is created

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, scp, inotify

In my work, I use 2 Linux servers.
The first one is used for web-crawling and create it as a text file.
The other one is used for analyzing the text file from the web crawler.

So the issue is that when a text file is created on web-crawling server,
it needs to be transferred automatically on the analysis server.

I've used shell programming guides referring some tips,
and set up the crawling server to be able to execute  the `scp` command without requiring the password (By using `ssh-keygen` command, Add `ssh-key` on `authorized_keys` file located in /root/.ssh directory)
But I cannot figure out how to programmatically transfer the file when it is created.

My job position is just data analyze (Not programming)
So, the lack of background programming knowledge is my big concern

If there is a way to trigger the `scp` to copy the file when it is created, please let me know.

Comment: Why does there need to be 2 computers? Can't the web crawler do analysis while crawling?

Comment: Look at `inotifywait`. Use it to watch the directory where the web-crawling file is created and have it `rsync` to the analyze box.

Comment: Why does there need to be 2 computers? Can't the web crawler do analysis while crawling?
>>> yes, but we need to use that analysis server. sadly...

Comment: Sure, but you asked about an automatic transfer *between* server? Did you get your `ssh` keys setup and working? Why are you using the `root` account for the ssh keys? The private key should go in `$HOME/.ssh` on web-crawler and the public-key in `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` on analyze.

Comment: @David C. Rankin Ah...there's no reason to use root account. and ssh key setup is working well (I checked it with scp command). 
Is the inotifywait command C language??

Comment: If you are adding the `ssh-key` to the `/root/.ssh` directory, you are allowing the user from server 1 to copy to server to as the root user.  That is a huge security risk that you should not be doing.  Add the key to the authorized_keys for the user under which the analysis software is running.

Comment: @David C. Rankin Then, Should I remove the KEY on root/.ssh/authorized_keys  and move in to $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
Right?

Comment: Yes, under the account that is running the analysis software.

Comment: @wottle thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `inotifywait` to monitor the directory and run a command every time a file is created in the directory.  In this case, you would fire off the `scp` command.  IF you have it set up to not prompt for the password, you should be all set.

```
inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /path/to/dir | while read FILE; do scp "$FILE"analysis_server:/path/on/anaylsis/server/; done
```

You can find out more about `inotifywait` at http://techarena51.com/index.php/inotify-tools-example/

Comment: Wow...Dir My Savior...<br/>
1. I install inotify-tools on server 1(crawler)<br/>
2. create shell script as below <br/>
#!/bin/sh

inotifywait -mrq -e CREATE --format %w%f /home/solugen/test/script/txt | while read FILE;
do scp "$FILE" 211.238.134.72:/data/chano/solugen_wordcloud/;
done
<br/>
Finally, It works perfect..<br/>
when a txt file is created on server 1, it is transfered to server 2 immediatly <br/>
Thank you! <br/>